# calling aaply caused a factor level error message

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I am modifying r code to use parallel processing. I called the libraries `"plyr"`, `"compiler"`, `"doParallel"`, `"foreach"`. Then set up processing on two cores, using `makeCluster()`, `registerDoParallel()`. Having done that, I called the function `aaply()`. However, I got a message error typical of factor() function.

I checked if I had omitted any relevant instruction to the functions makeCluster(), registerDoParallel() to enable the correct application of aaply().

Also, this call was outside loops or any other iterative instruction block.

## parallel processing conditional to multicores

```
Cores <- detectCores(logical = FALSE) # pick up cores in the system running the code

  if (Cores > 1 | is.na(Cores) == FALSE) {

cl <- makeCluster(Cores) # set computer clusters according to cores

registerDoParallel(cl, cores = Cores) # initialize parallelization

multicore <- TRUE } else multicore <- FALSE
```

....

```
Augmented.Y <- rbind(Eta.m, Y)

# stop("check aaply")

LL.items.old <- aaply(Augmented.Y, 
                      2, 
                      function(x) {

                      y.col <- x[-(1:dim(Eta.m)[1])]

                      eta   <- x[1:dim(Eta.m)[1]]

                      ll <- column.gsdlm.c(y.col, eta, theta.m) },

                      .inform = TRUE,

                      .parallel = multicore)
```

I expected the aaply() function to speed up the execution of the calculation previously assigned to a simple apply() call. Instead I got the following error message:

Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [4] is duplicated
In addition: Warning message:
Duplicate names not supported. 
Called from: factor(x, levels = x)

Any idea of what  is going on?

Comment: Could you add the example data and what is `column.gsdlm.c` ?

Comment: Sure. The Augmented.Y is a combination of Y matrix of binomial (0, 1) values combined with a smaller matrix Eta.m of continuos values, Y being observed data and Eta,m latent variables. theta.m is a latent variable vector, which is called externally, e.g. is already present in the memory. column.gsdlm.c is a sumproduct operation that generates a log-likelihood value. The idea is to produce a vector of values (LL.items.old) faster than a 'simple' apply call.

Comment: @Steve  Sorry, here is an example of the data Y = n x p, matrix, n = 100, p = 10, like                 row 1 1010000000 ... Eta.m = 2 x p, matrix -1.7 1.9 2.4 ....